# Turn Off screen for VNC use

Tags: linux, vnc

I am trying to use a machine for vnc.

I want the screen to be always off to save energy. I have tried to set the brightness to 0 but continues on. My idea is for example to change the terminal or something like tty2 where I have the desktop and boot in tty1 and that has the blank in 10 seconds, I do not know if this is possible or there will be a better way to do it.

I have tried xset dpms force off and in some distro it doesn't work but in the ones it works the screen turns off but when I move the mouse it turns on which doesn't solve my problem. I don't know if you can think of anything I can do. I was going to use vnc with guacamole server.

GNOME Desktop

Comment: seems simple - don't attach a screen, keyboard or mouse

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: First of all the screen is built in, the keyboard can be removed as well as the mouse but when you move the mouse from the vnc the screen turns on.

Comment: Secondly, apologies if I have not explained myself correctly, I have tried to convey it in the best possible way. I would like to turn off the local screen of the pc so that it does not show any image while using VNC and thus save power consumption. If the explanation is a bit complicated it is because I have tried to approach the problem in different ways but the main objective is to disable the computer screen so that it does not output (in older kernels setting the brightness to 0 would achieve this).